# Parse a line after a matching pattern in a file in a Perl script

Tags: regex, perl, file

Given a file in format:

```
Foo:
  var1 = 1
  var2 = 2
  var3 = 3
Bar: 
  var1 = 4
  var2 = 5
  var3 = 6
Baz:
  var1 = 7
  var2 = 8  
  var3 = 9
```

I would like to open this file, read it line by line and find occurence var3 which comes after pattern Baz and take the value 9 from it in a perl script. What is best regex to do this?

```
sub getValue {
    open($fh, $file);
    while(my $line = <$fh>) {
        chomp($line);
        if($line =~ "regex here" ) {
        my $value = $3;
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

So with correct regex, I expect this sub return value 9.

Comment: "Baz.*?var3 = (\d+)" might work, though you need to make sure that the dot matches newline, too. What regex have you tried so far?

Comment: You can't have the regex like you ask for. You go line-by-line while patterns are on separate lines.  Set a flag when you find the line with `Baz:`, unset when you find another section heading (a line with `:` but not `Baz`).  If the flag is true match on `var3`.   Or, read the whole file into a variable and then you can do multi-line match.

Comment: @Secespitus I think the "make sure `.` matches newline" is exactly the point of the question. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you process line by line you need to keep the state, to know when inside `Baz:` section

```
my $in_sec;

while (<$fh>) 
{    
    if    (/^Baz:/)     { $in_sec = 1; }
    elsif (/(?<!Baz):/) { $in_sec = 0; }

    if ($in_sec) {
        my ($num) = /var3\s*=\s*(\d+)/;
        say $num if $num;
    }   
}
```

The flag is turned off when another section starts, detected by using a [negative lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind).

Or, read the whole file into a scalar so that you can match across lines.

Please use lexical filehandles and the three-argument `open`, it's better.